# how to keep format cell from database to datatable c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

iam trying to get data from mysql table
to pass it into an excelsheet.

i use blazor and epplus library.

here is my code

```
    MySqlConnection con= new MySqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("default"));

    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheetData = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheetData.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
        pck.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"wwwroot/Ressources/test.xlsx"));
    }
```

it seems that not returning me right all data cause there is at least one column of date, and instead of date i have on my excelsheet's cell number like this one 44275

do i miss something? is there a way easier to pass data from database's table to an excelsheet?

Comment: That's how Excel stores dates...it's days since 1/1/1900. To get it to show up like you expect to see a date formatted, you need to specify a date format. I haven't used that library, but check this link out: https://riptutorial.com/epplus/example/26058/date-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: it's because like said @Jim, I have first to specify to the column that there will be date inside.

So in my case, formatted the column target on my template xlsx file to date format and it worked well. I saw the correct date like I wanted.